# PDF.JS viewer not working in Micorosft Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, pdf.js, microsoft-edge

I have use `PDF.js` and `Viewer.js` for print view.

**Explanation :**

Here I am giving option to client to print `.pdf` file as per requirement it is working fine with chrome but not working with `Microsoft Edge`, `IE11`, `Firefox`.

Working with chrome browser Image :

[image]

Not working with Microsoft Edge browser image.Here I could display a print view but pdf file is not properly visible.

[image]

JS Code as Below which is working fine with chrome.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    traditional: true,
    url: url,
    async: false,
    data: params,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data != null) {         
            $("#dvPrint").html("");
            // create and remove iframe for display pdf
            var frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');
            frame1.name = "frame1";
            frame1.id = "framePDFViewer";
            frame1.src = "/ViewerJS/#.." + data;
            frame1.width = 800;
            frame1.height = 50000;
            document.body.appendChild(frame1);
            setTimeout(function () {
                var canvas = $("canvas", $("#framePDFViewer").contents());
                for (var i = 0; i < canvas.length; i++) {
                    var img = "<img src='" + canvas[i].toDataURL() + "' />";
                    $("#dvPrint").html($("#dvPrint").html() + img);
                }

                document.body.removeChild(frame1);
                PrintDiv($("#dvPrint").html(), function () { $('#Loader').hide(); });
            }, 5000);                        
        }                        
    },
    error: function (e) {
        $('#Loader').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Not a solution but there is an issue here : https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/3983 There is a work-around mentioned but it will involve you modifying the publishers source. If you are planning on updating later keep this in mind.

Comment: @GovindaRajbhar Could you put a small demo online of the issue? Also, which build of Edge are you testing against?